# Writing variables to a session file manually with php

Tags: php, file, session, fopen

I have an unusual problem. I need to be able to alter a session variable manually for any given user's session (other than my own). The application manages employees in the call center.

Each user has a session variable called 'status' which can equal 'online', 'in-call', 'on-break', et cetera.

When the user is on break their `$_SESSION['status']` is changed to "on break". Some people have a habit of not clicking the "start break" button, so my boss asked if I could give her functionality to log people out from her admin-level account.

I do not want to convert the "on break" functionality to use a database because that would be one extra query I'd have to manually add to about 50 files.

I know that conventionally this is not possible, but I am hoping for some unconventional answers. For example, would this be possible by opening and writing to the session file on the server itself?

Comment: anyone at all? i'm trying to work my way through this but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not only possible but insanely easy. First, save the current session_id() to a variable, then session_write_close(), then start a new session with the session id of the session you want to edit, edit the session, then session_write_close again and start the session back up with the session_id saved in the aforementioned  variable.

```
$temp = array();
$temp['tempid'] = session_id();
foreach($_SESSION as $key=>$val){
    $temp[$key]=$val;
}
$MESSAGE = "<h2>You have been remotely logged out by admin.</h2><h3>Please see ".$_SESSION['fname']." ".$_SESSION['lname']." before returning to work.</h3>";
session_write_close(); //end admin sesh

session_id($_GET['session']); //start remote sesh
session_start(); 

//Make changes to remote sesh here

session_write_close();

session_id($temp['tempid']); //restart local sesh
session_start();
foreach($temp as $key=>$val){
    $_SESSION[$key]=$val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Whatever you are trying to do, trying to modify a session variable.  I don't think there is really anyway to do this without involving a database.  You can use session_id() to store your supervisor's session id, change her $_SESSION to another users, change the status, and then change it back to her own session, but I don't know how you can get their session id in the first place aside from putting it in a database when the session starts.

Fixing whatever is going on that requires you to change 50 different files to add one small piece of functionality would probably serve you better in the long run than "unconventional answers."

Comment: this is more or less what i want to do. all session id's are readily available in the database but the session variables are not. i think i'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you need to delete a user's session to log him out.  You can physically delete a specific user session file on the server, but it's fragile and insecure (IMHO).

It's better to save session in the database, then you can manipulate/delete it easily.  The official guide to write custom session handlers is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php).

If you don't want to write it yourself, you can use 3rd party solution, e.g. [this one](http://jameshalsall.co.uk/php-database-sessions/).

Answer (score 1):

if you are using apache server any kind of creation of session is saved inside a folder called tmp with names like 'sess409080ffgfsfs.tmp'. now you have to just find out which one of the existing files is the one you are looking for.